# C# trying to extract URLs from a webpage that have extentions .com, .net and .org

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract .com, .net and .org links from a single webpage that contains various numbers of these. I am just learning about Regex using C#, but I am not sure how to setup a pattern that looks for the just .com, .net and .org extensions. Then print those urls with those endings. Any suggestions or websites that you can direct me to help me would be great.

here is what i got so far

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string extPattern = @"?.com|?.net|?.org;  //but i think i am not doing this right. 
string source = client.DounloadString(url) //read the Url and store the pages. 
//then not sure what to do.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
string extPattern = @"(http://)?[a-z0-9\-\.]+(\.com|\.net|\.org)";
```

Anyway this is not the perfect way to achieve your goal because url are very different (could have http or https, with or without www).

Comment: I am not looking for the beginning of any of the string but rather the ending of every string and if it has a .com or .net I want to add it my array. So if my input was something like this  TEXT TEXT TEXT stackoverflow.com or if my input was TEXT TEXT TEXT www.stackoverflow.com, it would get both

Comment: I tried this pattern with something like http://www.google.com and it couldn't find it.

Comment: @user990951 I add the point char which I forgot. Now it works good as you can see trying here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 1):

It partially depends on the format you expect the input string to be in. The following pattern assumes each URL to be on a separate line:

(.+\.com|.+\.net|.+\.org)\s

This may or may not be what you need depending on the input format. You'll need to give more information if you want anything more useful.

Some decent online resources for testing .NET regexes are:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Or is the problem that you don't know how to use the .NET regex classes? There are many questions on this very site that could help you there.

If you're just looking for a regex to match a URL then you will find one on here:

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=1&categoryId=2

Comment: its page source that is one long string.

Comment: @user990951: see the link at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your downloaded data into a string and use regex like this.

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"(http://)?[a-z0-9\-]+(\.com|\.net|\.org)");
MatchCollection collection = myRegex.Matches(downloadedData);
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(collection[0]);
}
```